# Looping through js function parameter

Tags: javascript, php

I have below js.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      editable: false,


      events: [
        {
          title: 'Absent',
          start: new Date(y, m, 9),
          color: '#008aaf '
        }
      ]


    });
```

The above js generates a calendar for me. The **events** parameter marks the event on the date specified in start field. Now i have to generate event dynamically based on my php **date** array which is as shown below:

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => 28/07/2014
        [1] => 30/07/2014
        [2] => 01/08/2014
        [3] => 29/07/2014
    )
```

How can i generate events based on php **date** array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  editable: false,

  events: [
  <?php
    foreach($dateArray as $date)
    {
        $dateParts = explode("/",$date);
        $dates[] = "{
          title: 'Absent',
          start: new Date(".$dateParts[2].", ".$dateParts[1].", ".$dateParts[0]."),
          color: '#008aaf '
        }";
    }
    echo implode(",",$dates);
  ?>
  ]
});
```